# Where are good places to start learning VB?

Tags: vb.net

The only programming language I know is C++, and I would like to learn some others, specifically Visual Basic.  So — what are some good beginners tutorials for VB, and what others languages would you suggest are good ideas to learn?

Comment: vb or vb.net? if vb.net - http://www.msdn.microsoft.com/vbasic

Comment: I guess C++ developers (experienced) will goto c++/cli or c#

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vbasic/ms789086.aspx

Answer (score 5):

I suggest you to start with C#, because is more related to C++ and will give you a good introduction to .net

Petzold book [.NET Book Zero - What the C or C++ Programmer Needs to Know About C# and the .NET Framework](http://www.charlespetzold.com/dotnet/) is perfect for the task (free)

Then you can learn VB.net, a cousin of C#.

Answer (score 0):

You'll find tons of articles and videos on http://www.asp.net/learn

Enjoy

Answer (score 0):

If you already want the tutorials, here is a good site to begin: http://cuinl.tripod.com/tutorials.htm , but here is good too: www.tutorialized.com/tutorials/Visual-Basic/1 . Sorry about my english.

Answer (score 0):

> what are some good beginners tutorials for VB

http://www.programmersheaven.com/2/VB-NET-School

> what others languages would you suggest are good ideas to learn?

For a powerful language with similar syntax as C++: C#

For a rapid development scripting language: Python